# What are the advantages of time-varying graph CNNs compared to fixed graph?

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, graphs, geometric-deep-learning, graph-theory

As I wrote in the title, what are the advantages of time-varying graph CNNs compared to fixed graph? For example, in CORA, which is a graph of citation relations of papers frequently used in graph CNN, what examples are there?

Comment: Are you asking the difference between the architectures? CORA is a dataset. "what examples are there?", of what?

Comment: @nbro i mean what is the advantage of using CNN of a time-varying graph to CORA compared to using CNN of a fixed graph to CORA?

Comment: What do you mean by CNN of a time-varying graph and CNN of a fixed graph? Do you mean respectively a time-varying GCN and a non-time-varying GCN?

Comment: @nbro yes, sorry for my bad english